# How to Test For Both Null and Not Null Columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, null

Say I have a table with two columns called A, and B. I want to get a result set that fulfills the following criteria:

Get result set where

1. Column A is null
2. Column B is not null

So I do the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM myTestTable WHERE columnA IS NULL and columnB IS NOT NULL;
```

But it throws an error?

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "But it throws an error" is not helpful. Please give the exact error message.

Comment: It just says "You have error in your MySQL syntax near columnA IS NULL AND..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE!

This query will work with the added backticks (`) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTestTable` WHERE `columnA` IS NULL and `columnB` IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted the error you're getting but you can try this.

```
CREATE table ex(column1 varchar(10), column2 varchar(10));

INSERT into ex VALUES(NULL,'gvd');
INSERT into ex VALUES(NULL,'vish');
insert into ex VALUES('b',NULL);
insert into ex VALUES(NULL,NULL);

SELECT * FROM ex
where column1 is NULL AND column2 is NOT null;

column1    column2
---------- ----------
NULL       vish
NULL       gvd
```

(2 row(s) affected)

Well it works fine in my case follow the above queries.

Comment: thank you :-) However, the above does not work for me. Nevertheless, this one works: SELECT * FROM ex WHERE 'column1' IS NULL and 'column2' IS NOT NULL. The difference is in addition of the apostrophes. Wonder why...

Comment: @HoneyBadger: When you use apostrophes, that's referring to a *value* I wouldn't expect that query to return any results.